# regular expression detect any number of digits separated by only an hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

At the moment I am using `\b\d-\d\b` with no success.

I would like to use an regular expression which is valid in the following cases:

Any number of digits (at least one numeric value) separated by only a hyphen.

Regular expression is valid in this cases:

```
1-1
2-22
03-03
4-44
555-555
```

and so on.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and point me out a good example?

Notes: I need to return true or false from the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number of digits (but at least one) would be `\d+`, where the `+` says to match the preceding part one or more times (equivalent to `\d{1,}`). So:

```
\b\d+-\d+\b
```

For a list of the regex features that JavaScript supports, check out [MDN's regular expressions page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

**Update:** In a comment the OP mentioned trying to match against a string `"1-25656{{}"`. To actually extract the number part from a longer string, use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var matches = inputString.match(/\b\d+-\d+\b/);
```

...which will return `null` if there is no match, otherwise will return an array containing the first match. To get all matches add the `g` (global) flag:

```
var matches = inputString.match(/\b\d+-\d+\b/g);
```

**Final update:** If you want to test whether a string contains nothing but two numbers separated by a hyphen use this expression:

```
^\d+-\d+$

var isValid = /^\d+-\d+$/.test(inputString);
```

Comment: could you please double check here https://regex101.com/r/bN8lS9/1 if I am adding 1-25656{{} does not work

Comment: But...the regex at that link *did* match the `1-25656` part of the string. In JS, if you say `"1-25656{{}".match(/\b\d+-\d+\b/)` you'll get back `["1-25656"]`. If you want to match all such numbers in a longer string, add the `g` flag, so `yourString.match(/\b\d+-\d+\b/g)`.

Comment: Please look at this example, I need to return false for isValid at the moment it return true.
var data = '1-50{}';
var isValid = /\b\d+-\d+\b/g.test(data);

Comment: Never use `RegExp.test` with a global modifier `/g`.

Comment: could you please provide me an example for isValid, thanks for your support

Comment: @GibboK: If you **ONLY** want to have numbers and hyphens, apply anchors like in Tushar's comment.

Comment: @revo: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results